# SSRS Row visibility based on another row's visibility

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, visibility

My SSRS report has the requirement to filter the report based on a cashier's variance to balancing to 0.  My variance is a calculation based on two different datasets and values within those data sets.

I've used some custom code in order to pull some of the data from a second data set and then I use ReportItems! expressions to calculate the variance with it all combined in one chart.  The requirement is to only show those cashiers that are off balancing by more than +/-$10.  I've tried to put the ReportItem! expression in the filter for the tablix, but the filters won't take a ReportItem! expression.  My next thought was to just hide the rows that don't meet my criteria, but when I do this one of my toggled rows unhides itself because it's parent is hidden now based on my row visibility expression.  Is it possible to hide all child rows of hidden rows? Ideally, I'd turn this into a parameter so that the end user can change the range of what data to look at.

Comment: It would create some unhappy overhead, but have you tried putting another call to the Custom Code in your tablix filter?

Comment: I did try to put the custom code in the tablix filter and it didn't work.  The hidden row idea was just an idea, if there was a way that I could exclude these rows coming into the data, I would, but I can't figure out how to filter the data based on a calculation that isn't included in the source data. I've thought about adding it to the source data, but I'm not sure it's worth the effort for this one requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but I had to put group visibility settings on it as well as the row where all the other row groups I only had to do the group.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try hiding the Group instead of the rows? Usually if there's a child within a group that is hidden, the child will hide too...